# Can't play balazar game

Tags: games

I am not able to play balazar game in ubuntu 12.04.  I am able to play it when I run it using terminal disabling the sound like this:

```
balazar --no-sound
```

Is there any way to play it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Balazar 2 game is not being given support right now.
The creator has abandoned the game. It might be supported in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Inre; Balazar III: start game from console with your usual --no-sound flag, then, in the options menu; make sure you have unchecked the music. there are working sounds (when you strike something, when you or an enemy are struck "AAAH!"....that's about it. Then, you can close game and call it without the --no-sound flag. You will soon want to disable sound, once you hear it, though! This game is a work in progress. Don't expect much yet.